# How to change options in list.js List object

Tags: javascript, listjs

Is there a way to change the options in list.js without creating a new object? Looking through [the documentation](http://www.listjs.com/docs/options) it seems the only way to set them is in the constructor. That works, but if I can avoid creating another object each time the user changes an option (what fields are being searched/filtered on), I'd rather re-use the same one.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use direct DOM manipulation to manipulate target items, you can also look at their [Existing List + Add Example](http://www.listjs.com/examples/existing-list-add)